# how to have conditional part in gdbinit based on the environnment

Tags: gdb, gdbinit

In the [gdb manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#Command-Files) there is this part:

> **if else**
>
> This command allows to include in your script conditionally
>   executed commands. The if command takes a single argument, which is an
>   expression to evaluate...

I can perform tests in my gdbinit when I use a numeric expression, like

```
if (42 == 42)
    print "42"
end
```

But when I want to perform a test on a String, like this:

```
if ("a" == "a")
    print "yes"
end
```

then I got an error when I start gdb:

```
.gdbinit:45: Error in sourced command file:
You can't do that without a process to debug.
```

I tried, unsuccessfully, to find documentation or examples for the expression syntax in order to write my conditional block.

What I want to achieve is to add a bunch of command based on an environment variable. So I need to have this kind of section in my gdbinit:

```
if ("${myEnvVar}" == "someSpecialValue")
    #my set of special values
end
```

How to achieve that ?

edit: looks like the easiest way is to use python to perform this kind of operation: [How to access environment variables inside .gdbinit and inside gdb itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814185/how-to-access-environment-variables-inside-gdbinit-and-inside-gdb-itself)

If there's no way to achieve this with 'pure' gdb commands, I guess that this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Did you try something like `(strcmp($myVar, "hello") == 0`?

Comment: It generates the "You can't do that without a process to debug." error... It's a bit sad that a python call is required to perform this kind of operation, but it opens new perspective at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you.

Comment: Try `if ($_streq(stringval1, stringval2))`

Comment: Same result unfortunately :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to achieve that ?

If you have GDB with embedded Python (most recent GDB builds do), you have full power of Python at your disposal.

For example:

```
# ~/.gdbinit
source ~/.gdbinit.py

# ~/.gdbinit.py
import os

h = os.getenv("MY_ENV_VAR")
if h:
  print "MY_ENV_VAR =", h
  gdb.execute("set history size 100")
  # Put other settings here ...
else:
  print "MY_ENV_VAR is unset"
```

Let's see if it works:

```
$ gdb -q 
MY_ENV_VAR is unset
(gdb) q

$ MY_ENV_VAR=abc gdb -q 
MY_ENV_VAR = abc
(gdb)
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to do it apparently, and in this case my question is a duplicate... IMHO it's sad that one needs to run a python script for a simple test based on the env variables...